# Array creation too slow

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, opencv

I am trying to create an image array from scratch.
I got the code running but it takes arrounds 30 secs to run it.
I feel it could be faster by using numpy native functions.
How can I do this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

volumes = np.random.randint(low=0, high=200, size=10000)
print(volumes)

image_heigh = 128
image_width = 256
image_channel = 3

show_img = False


def nomralized(data, data_min, data_max, maximum_value):

    nomamized_data = maximum_value * ((data - data_min) / (data_max - data_min))

    return nomamized_data

start_time = time.time()

for ii in range(len(volumes)-image_width):
    # ===================== part to optimize start
    final_image = np.zeros((image_heigh, image_width, image_channel))

    start = ii
    end = ii + image_width

    current_vols = volumes[start:end]

    # nomalize data
    vol_min = 0
    vol_max = np.max(current_vols)

    vol_norm = nomralized(data=current_vols,
                      data_min=vol_min,
                      data_max=vol_max,
                      maximum_value=image_heigh)

    for xxx in range(image_width):
        final_image[:int(vol_norm[xxx]), xxx, :] = 1

    # ===================== part to optimize end

    if show_img:
        image = np.float32(final_image)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.imshow("ok", image)
        cv2.waitKey(27)

print("total running time: ", (time.time() - start_time))
```

How can I do to make this image array creation faster?
I need to create the image every timesteps because I want to simulate real live data stream that come every new timesteps.

This is why I would like to optimize only this part of the code :

```
for xxx in range(image_width):
    final_image[:int(vol_norm[xxx]), xxx, :] = 1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I've just implemented simple optimization for your inner loop, using `np.arange(...)` instead of your inner loop. My running time is now `2.6 sec` instead of `27 sec` that was before. See this optimization in the beginning of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64319607/941531).

Comment: Also another very useful optimization that I didn't do is that you don't need to recompute previous image in a case when max/min of whole data didn't change. You need to recompute previous image data only in the case if max/min changed. And I expect that your real-life data is gradually chaning like Forex or Bitcoin prices, hence max/min change very non-often.

Comment: I've just implemented above mentioned (in previous comment) optimization (regarding not-recomputing image if min/max didn't change) plus all other optimizations inside simulation of live process at the very end of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64319607/941531), there is also animated PNG with rendered process, png-rendering code is also inside live process simulation. Also I model there process of gradually changing plot same like Forex prices.

Comment: Just also added axes drawing to my last visualization of real-time process in my answer, using matplotlib library.

Comment: I just figured out how to optimize your inner loop even twice more. Now running time is 1.3 sec instead of 2.6 sec before. [Here is full code](https://cutt.ly/DganJU3). But I put back 3 channels as in original question and made float32. These both reduced speed to 2.8 sec, but still this good time is possible due to last optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First simplest optimizations are next:

1. Use comparing values to `np.arange(...)` instead of inner loop.
2. Use gray image instead of 3-channels RGB. 3 times less data to process.
3. Use np.uint8 type instead of np.float32, which is faster to process and doesn't need conversion to float32 for CV2 visualizing.

All these above optimizations give huge speedup (`10x` times), and my running time is `2.6 sec` instead of `27 sec` before.

Also another very useful optimization that I didn't do is that you don't need to recompute previous image pixels in a case when max/min of whole data within current window didn't change. You need to recompute previous image data only in the case if max/min changed. And I expect that your real-life data is gradually changing like Forex or Bitcoin prices, hence max/min change within a window is very non-often.

Optimizations 1)-3) mentioned above are implemented in the next code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

volumes = np.random.randint(low=0, high=200, size=10000)
print(volumes)

image_heigh = 128
image_width = 256
image_channel = 3

show_img = False

def nomralized(data, data_min, data_max, maximum_value):

    nomamized_data = maximum_value * ((data - data_min) / (data_max - data_min))

    return nomamized_data

start_time = time.time()

aranges = np.arange(image_heigh, dtype = np.int32)[:, None]

for ii in range(len(volumes)-image_width):
    # ===================== part to optimize start
    #final_image = np.zeros((image_heigh, image_width, image_channel), dtype = np.float32)

    start = ii
    end = ii + image_width

    current_vols = volumes[start:end]

    # nomalize data
    vol_min = 0
    vol_max = np.max(current_vols)

    vol_norm = nomralized(data=current_vols,
                      data_min=vol_min,
                      data_max=vol_max,
                      maximum_value=image_heigh)

    final_image = (aranges < vol_norm[None, :].astype(np.int32)).astype(np.uint8) * 255

    # ===================== part to optimize end

    if show_img:
        cv2.imshow('ok', final_image)
        cv2.waitKey(27)

print("total running time: ", (time.time() - start_time))
```

For above code I just did one more optimization of inner loop which speed-up code above even `2x` times more to have timings of `1.3 sec`. But also I put back 3 channels plus float32, this reduced speed resulting in final `2.8 sec`, [here is the code](https://tio.run/##jVTbjpswEH3nK0bbhzVdQhOibStUXvtSqT8QRcgKDljFNjIm2ezPp@MLWbNNq/rBl/GZ25mxh4vplNxer1wMShs4nIokbOUkhgvQEeQwiwwXLElOqp8EG6HCm1xT2SjhFi4N6dW5WmfQ8barijXuRv7Kqs0aR5oM2kKCepqgVdqyumMIRmOb4muQnHljrKR4/hwkh45KyXqUbZNk7NS55qLF03fajxhRw44gldC0R28NaaihGdi5FlzOO/qSAU5cTKI@0X5iaZkkgAM1qbCKtQWi1QUKPgJxFmF1M5nCJyCz1VieeouamUnLd4YxcEO1qS2J6MQuuZ0IKlHkr71RygZGDSG49XISEYXZmMvAPBLp3Bbp7qeSLINyD9/grg48weaeXpmBVd2nOR3tpfV47BWdL@f7DBZVyAD5sbGuNhj6UWngHLgE77dn8lbiVVRPZNtS8wGqewMGavtLgRqQE@QMHFle5cgl7Wtny8f/yrQayZKWyNW7eNNF7nOCvlLOC15w7o5MNu6AjEX2PPQwac2kqTE5m3zIcecslKi4T0KCtuy2EV1bOBlibXug1vrtjJ3jAsINiW2HyCxGKi0saNnaVYzOHPjPMbdkFXz/G0dfqhDT33CLN1FFzIdwlzUK/bwjtyyeYJ0/x43me3CfG4SOgxoZwR7FD2OuzH83ClLvNfgR5q@hvGWBH1rOhZWTR/XrMYsDTReoM@XmB7uQ4gtG4L@qB6MM7UFPUnLZuidbwkMGJHq8@Pzf3jV@ANfrbw)

Another next optimization is possible if re-computing old images data is not needed.

Main thing to be optimized was that you were re-computing almost same whole image on each step with 1 pixel shift-step along width. Instead of this you need to compute whole image once, then shift right not 1 pixel but whole image width.

Then after this optimization running time is `0.08 sec`.

And do 1 pixel stepping only for showing animation, not for computing image data, image data should be computed just once if you need speed.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

volumes = np.random.randint(low=0, high=200, size=10000)
print(volumes)

image_heigh = 128
image_width = volumes.size #256
image_channel = 3
screen_width = 256

show_img = False


def nomralized(data, data_min, data_max, maximum_value):

    nomamized_data = maximum_value * ((data - data_min) / (data_max - data_min))

    return nomamized_data

start_time = time.time()

for ii in range(0, len(volumes), image_width):
    # ===================== part to optimize start
    final_image = np.zeros((image_heigh, image_width, image_channel))

    start = ii
    end = ii + image_width

    current_vols = volumes[start:end]

    # nomalize data
    vol_min = 0
    vol_max = np.max(current_vols)

    vol_norm = nomralized(data=current_vols,
                      data_min=vol_min,
                      data_max=vol_max,
                      maximum_value=image_heigh)

    for xxx in range(image_width):
        final_image[:int(vol_norm[xxx]), xxx, :] = 1

    # ===================== part to optimize end

    if show_img:
        for start in range(0, final_image.shape[1] - screen_width):
            image = np.float32(final_image[:, start : start + screen_width])
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            cv2.imshow("ok", image)
            cv2.waitKey(27)

print("total running time: ", (time.time() - start_time))
```

I also created animation image out of your data:

[image: img]

If you want to create same animation just append next piece of code to the end of script above:

```
# Needs: python -m pip install pillow
import PIL.Image
imgs = [PIL.Image.fromarray(final_image[:, start : start + screen_width].astype(np.uint8) * 255) for start in range(0, final_image.shape[1] - screen_width, 6)]
imgs[0].save('result.png', append_images = imgs[1:], save_all = True, lossless = True, duration = 100)
```

I've implemented also simulation of real-time live stream data rendering/visualizing.

1. `live_stream()` generator spits out random amount of data at random points of time, this is to simulate data generation process.
2. `stream_fetcher()` listens to live stream and records all data received to python queue `q0`, this fetcher is run in one thread.
3. `renderer()` gets data recorded by fetcher and renders it into image through your mathematical formulas and normalization process, it renders as much data as available, resulting in images with varying widths, rendered images are saved to another queue `q1`.
4. `visualizer()` visualizes rendered data by fetching as much rendered images as available.

All functions run in separate threads not to block whole process. Also if any of threads works to slow then it skips some of data to catch-up with current real-time data, thus every queue doesn't overflow.

Also you may see that visualized process is jumpy, it is not because functions are somewhat slow, but because live stream spits out different amount of data in each time step, this is how usually real-time data may behave.

In the next code I did also extra optimization mentioned before, that is not-recomputing image if min/max didn't change.

```
import cv2, numpy as np
import time, random, threading, queue

image_height = 256
image_width = 512

# Make results reproducible and deterministic
np.random.seed(0)
random.seed(0)

def live_stream():
    last = 0.
    while True:
        a = np.random.uniform(low = -1., high = 1., size = random.randint(1, 20)).astype(np.float64).cumsum() + last
        yield a
        last = a[-1]
        time.sleep(random.random() * 0.1)

q0 = queue.Queue()
def stream_fetcher():
    for e in live_stream():
        q0.put(e)

threading.Thread(target = stream_fetcher, daemon = True).start()

aranges = np.arange(image_height, dtype = np.int32)[:, None]

q1 = queue.Queue()
def renderer():
    def normalized(data, data_min, data_max, maximum_value):
        nomamized_data = maximum_value * ((data - data_min) / (data_max - data_min))
        return nomamized_data

    prev_image = np.zeros((image_height, 0), dtype = np.uint8)
    prev_vols = np.zeros((0,), dtype = np.float64)
        
    while True:        
        data = []
        data.append(q0.get())
        try:
            while True:
                data.append(q0.get(block = False))
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
                
        vols = np.concatenate(data)[-image_width:]
        prev_vols = prev_vols[-(image_width - vols.size) or prev_vols.size:]
        concat_vols = np.concatenate((prev_vols, vols))[-image_width:]
        vols_min, vols_max = np.amin(concat_vols), np.amax(concat_vols)
        if prev_vols.size > 0 and (vols_min < np.amin(prev_vols) - 10 ** -8 or vols_max > np.amax(prev_vols) + 10 ** -8):
            vols = concat_vols
            prev_image = prev_image[:, :-prev_vols.size]
            prev_vols = prev_vols[:0]

        vols_norm = normalized(
            data = vols, data_min = vols_min,
            data_max = vols_max, maximum_value = image_height,
        )
        
        image = (aranges < vols_norm.astype(np.int32)[None, :]).astype(np.uint8) * 255
        whole_image = np.concatenate((prev_image, image), axis = 1)[:, -image_width:]
        
        q1.put(whole_image)
        
        prev_image = whole_image
        prev_vols = concat_vols

threading.Thread(target = renderer, daemon = True).start()


def visualizer():
    imgs = []
    
    while True:
        data = []
        data.append(q1.get())
        try:
            while True:
                data.append(q1.get(block = False))
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        image = np.concatenate(data, axis = 1)[:, -image_width:]
        cv2.imshow('ok', image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

        if imgs is not None:
            try:
                # Needs: python -m pip install pillow
                import PIL.Image
                has_pil = True
            except:
                has_pil = False
                imgs = None
            if has_pil:
                imgs.append(PIL.Image.fromarray(np.pad(image, ((0, 0), (image_width - image.shape[1], 0)), constant_values = 0)))

                if len(imgs) >= 1000:
                    print('saving...', flush = True)
                    imgs[0].save('result.png', append_images = imgs[1:], save_all = True, lossless = True, duration = 100)
                    imgs = None
                    print('saved!', flush = True)

threading.Thread(target = visualizer, daemon = True).start()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Above live process simulation is rendered into `result.png` which I show down below:

[image: img]

I've also decided to improve visualization, by using more advanced `matplotlib` instead of `cv2` to be able to show axes and doing real-time plot drawing. Visualization image is down below:

[image: img]

Next is a matplotlib-based code corresponding to last image above:

```
import cv2, numpy as np
import time, random, threading, queue

image_height = 256
image_width = 512
save_nsec = 20
dpi, fps = 100, 15

# Make results reproducible and deterministic
np.random.seed(0)
random.seed(0)

def live_stream():
    last = 0.
    pos = 0
    while True:
        a = np.random.uniform(low = -1., high = 1., size = random.randint(1, 30)).astype(np.float64).cumsum() + last
        yield a, pos, pos + a.size - 1
        pos += a.size
        last = a[-1]
        time.sleep(random.random() * 2.2 / fps)

q0 = queue.Queue()
def stream_fetcher():
    for e in live_stream():
        q0.put(e)

threading.Thread(target = stream_fetcher, daemon = True).start()

aranges = np.arange(image_height, dtype = np.int32)[:, None]

q1 = queue.Queue()
def renderer():
    def normalized(data, data_min, data_max, maximum_value):
        nomamized_data = maximum_value * ((data - data_min) / (data_max - data_min))
        return nomamized_data

    prev_image = np.zeros((image_height, 0), dtype = np.uint8)
    prev_vols = np.zeros((0,), dtype = np.float64)
        
    while True:        
        data = []
        data.append(q0.get())
        try:
            while True:
                data.append(q0.get(block = False))
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
            
        data_vols = [e[0] for e in data]
        data_minx, data_maxx = data[0][1], data[-1][2]

        vols = np.concatenate(data_vols)[-image_width:]
        prev_vols = prev_vols[-(image_width - vols.size) or prev_vols.size:]
        concat_vols = np.concatenate((prev_vols, vols))[-image_width:]
        vols_min, vols_max = np.amin(concat_vols), np.amax(concat_vols)
        if prev_vols.size > 0 and (vols_min < np.amin(prev_vols) - 10 ** -8 or vols_max > np.amax(prev_vols) + 10 ** -8):
            vols = concat_vols
            prev_image = prev_image[:, :-prev_vols.size]
            prev_vols = prev_vols[:0]

        vols_norm = normalized(
            data = vols, data_min = vols_min,
            data_max = vols_max, maximum_value = image_height,
        )
        
        image = (aranges < vols_norm.astype(np.int32)[None, :]).astype(np.uint8) * 255
        whole_image = np.concatenate((prev_image, image), axis = 1)[:, -image_width:]
        
        q1.put((whole_image, data_maxx - whole_image.shape[1] + 1, data_maxx, vols_min, vols_max))
        
        prev_image = whole_image
        prev_vols = concat_vols

threading.Thread(target = renderer, daemon = True).start()


def visualizer():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.animation
    
    def images():
        while True:
            data = []
            data.append(q1.get())
            try:
                while True:
                    data.append(q1.get(block = False))
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
            minx = min([e[1] for e in data])
            maxx = min([e[2] for e in data])
            miny = min([e[3] for e in data])
            maxy = min([e[4] for e in data])
            image = np.concatenate([e[0] for e in data], axis = 1)[:, -image_width:]
            image = np.pad(image, ((0, 0), (image_width - image.shape[1], 0)), constant_values = 0)
            image = np.repeat(image[:, :, None], 3, axis = -1)
            yield image, minx, maxx, miny, maxy
            
    it = images()
    im = None
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (image_width / dpi, image_height / dpi), dpi = dpi)
            
    def animate_func(i):
        nonlocal it, im, fig
        image, minx, maxx, miny, maxy = next(it)
        print(f'.', end = '', flush = True)
        if im is None:
            im = plt.imshow(image, interpolation = 'none', aspect = 'auto')
        else:
            im.set_array(image)
        im.set_extent((minx, maxx, miny, maxy))
        return [im]
            
    anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_func, frames = round(save_nsec * fps), interval = 1000 / fps)
    
    print('saving...', end = '', flush = True)
    #anim.save('result.mp4', fps = fps, dpi = dpi, extra_args = ['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
    anim.save('result.gif', fps = fps, dpi = dpi, writer = 'imagemagick')
    print('saved!', end = '', flush = True)
    
    plt.show()

threading.Thread(target = visualizer, daemon = True).start()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Then I've decided to play a bit and colored last image with RGB palette, the higher the peak is more red-ish it is, if it is more in the middle then it is more green-ish, if it is low enough then it is more blue-ish. Resulting image below was achieved by [this coloring code](https://tio.run/##jVhLb9s4EL7rV3DRg6lEVmQnKQpjW2AP29susEBvhmEwEm0T1SsSldj989lvSD0o2U4aIDY1Gs57Pg5dnvShyO/f3lRWFpVm8csyYHmTlScmapaXXkvXKpMBq0SeFFnA9KGSIlH5PmDPjWykBzaxl9uDVPuDZl/Z8vFzS3pViT6A8rhYtpT4IPJcpjWI914tXuQ2r2WMp0XkJaUK2K6szVMUsC@e94n9I35KVsm6SXWN77IqkiZWT6lkMIclUssqU7mqtYq9vAytkWEtZcIj35s8eoncsVRBa63hRMb9lcfwl4qaDI9C81QWZEJk1q8HBVU/qkZaTvoTeDuoanK1K6qMp8Ur6PNFGLADAkFOYFmrXxLLlpe@VK75ImCPke@HUHsqJYewXVoI/fnBD@MmqxsYxm6NVb3Sk5JpwkRA1pkPMIjQiJ@zRc9mXnxt3/TU1j@xni82PZGyGtaplCV3zCtI9w1bhkt2R8lA0J4j7DWpDv@jT@6bONoQbndSxwdZdaFELJhkKr8UZvp7jsKy0VxCbl9I4Q@z4lpUe0mGjkUHLBEyK3K8oET4YQ1GDSs8AYv3srb5@CWrouZ8VIy3DKF2Kd1TV4c@hFMOrAiThful71nmbaYSvBhJvLtjS4@cVOSk0X@msnW32j9hNyxChgaBPuI6PAVsvHvO1JQh8pnaQd23rw6ZwXbJOLpETeU5TGfSfGNYJuqf1mFx7oDP/mTKsLXRXaMracem21KJE4dvFyO3/rfIgRX2c2WLzXteXCygSuaJrIbSIVqOVhIpajfhidCCUq8FLM@7lTiSNUeVNdn2RaQoh6G28iITGe3dEi90jhhR1dwIRVg6qRQd3gl26X4vtJK6qfKJbM8CRSVftiZ2VysQ6Xu/5BrgwRd/EPdSpON6joILNQqk6A2c4tSIbuJqg7HejCihKEskgKMh0XTc8VhXpyGm10DwHVFPaRFTfX0XqFFHrjzGstRtIfydlXqiphR1PSKM7O0is5braDPADL0aO0b5Ow7lcsQeWmPXerGxdMLB9XLj9fuGqMdFHgstc/zzXq2/njsH2mrQ56asX6/n3D3@5ka6AWSfweyez5AcYVb19rItvN8WGHn@VZvore0YuxLHtnFB444OlJWhiuOI2ssB6IxNZd9YZE5d3qkAVHSCe1afzqOI3dyw@RdytzfiW6/O4b3tef1xMbRRcCwb14rbesPDegXUmY/N3pxvPMvYKpoUw5aAiOI24JE3LXu8tvnoqq4lmOCfcbeJ6MIxQbHJMTNsn/S5SUzrdofPfDD4FjPMoztXAF2AyptQg7fGcCBp9gAkLQe5r4cilS6MnZededniGMoGhpshzadwX6nC4cBfmAOfO2rc5py7@sP6IEqJNrUHd88VXChq/0JkRlXhyL3Yr25pvTOLdKfU9SnEHGYvqm5MofTHWTs8Z0KXaaFT9RSWJ1rRbF2mOnDfiBx2alXkXu8PCTXG1@74dA2KzzH@DJwXU5y/iPUf4f0Vsdcw/3dw/yL2E4jTCQ5oWZuKGCP@WEML8y3z8gNmlZ8G5vsPJTvMD@8zX@mhSyfW7zXRRGiJumwbiOYCTIb9@NgdNeM2alkMKxYwCkWbaws55pJz2QErlK4Bj4/hNVBxCM4QMxXVwvLKvXkM95nWG3ti206n9Jj16XwWULqTiKZomwwUmjbt5UPtCdZTHWLVVJLjq72BjeJ0x8xdczzYE41GrVLRxID1uX7qSduqcrtr8pir0fSZowlECitJdEDWjDH7mqOUXXnUXGnfQSq6KO5m4Sxg6DOwzLDapU196BDIPakRB5QTBWI1SUMbEJXVh@K1Kx/IllVZpAZzSDaMl5Av6lLGFOSZaHQxc2Y3tPVUMq7VemuvA/Zk8Cbv4JOEE/yy1@cz9lplm/OgU8DNLH@OluF3JOGv7omyHYzyg4BVIjOVXhUN0Gr4xeHGXG7bSKAf7I8OUXfp7bXbPMywkQ6H8KN0fCL1IanhM/urRZiVD7Pudw18OhUGUUcczIjh3ky2s/lLXCQyBvsMfh6Xnx9mLcSci92r3VWxr5WCV2SkSQz@Vfxz5k8ckskfH3hjN0CZqZ13r@zD@Xf9oJyeK84vEFG48L23t/8B):

[image: img]

And another one colored animation below, line-style instead of bar-style, with the help of [this code](https://tio.run/##jVhbj9o4FH7Pr/CqDzgzIQ3MZbtoW2kftm@70kp9Qwh5EgNWEyeTODPQP9/9jnNzAswUCXCOj8/95hQnc8j13c@fKivy0rD4ZRkwXWfFiYmK6cJr4UZlMmCl0EmeBcwcSikSpfcBe65lLT2gib3cHqTaHwz7zJYPjy3oVSXmAMjDYtlC4oPQWqYVgHdeJV7kVlcypkP3XlKogO0K2ltEUcAevaM8mlIE7GT/Cf4HJFwsP3neB/aP@C5ZKas6NRX@izJP6lg9pZJBUJZII8tMaVUZFXu6CBvxw0rKhEe@N3n0ErljqYI8lYF6GfdXHsMnFRWpFIX2qchJuMiuXw8KrL6VtWww6UMiDqxqrXZ5mfE0fwV8vggDdoCJSA0sK/VDYtni0p/Shi8C9nvk@yHYngrJQWyX5sI83vthXGdVDcHYrZWqZ3pSMk0YrATp7A8QRGjJz9miR7Mbn9udHtrqJ9bzxaYHkr/DKpWy4I54OfG@YctwyT6Sm2C05whnbRCE/9Ev960dGxNud9LEB1l2poQtmGRKXzIzfZ6jsKgNl6Dbh1j4za64EeVekqBj0gFLhMxyjQ1yhB9WQDSQwhOQeC@rxh8/ZJlXnI/C9JbB1G9DuqcuZn2wI680RK1f7pa@1yBvM5VgY0Tx40e29EjtopQvpLkV6kwOxz5xXb6LR59y/wRmnBP@nA0S@HDN8BSwMY050Z@iRD5TO8v4y2dng0FhyTjSkLYmVB20CzT9IR8aL6xJf0soYEhJ3j/6bMUycXQB0HPTGFiUpThxaHrZ7ETfe15cDMBS6kSWQ@gRTCMVRYrYT3gijKDQMQLi6m4ljgEJo7I6276IFOE02Fvnmcjo7JZwwXOEiKzgliis0VElk/COsAsfrFNKU5d6QttrCg0MsrW@uxrB8NzbAVqjnnzyB3IveTrOhyi4ENGoNL2A0zo3glu7NsZYb0aQUBQFHMCR0Eha7mhsytNg02tF9A1ST2kefwfDrwLB6dCVx1gWpg2Ev7PCTNgUoqpGgJG8nWXWch1thjJFW2PFyH/HIVyOOENrnFovNg2c6uh6ufH6c4PV41zHwkiNL@/Z@uu50ypXAz/XZf16PeduY51b6rag@6wtM9se5BBrWG8vy8L7Y4Gl51@ViXabjGlW4thmKiW1wwNhZaHIbBfa00G9GYvKvrDIdm3esWB/9oR7VJ/6WcRubtj8E6nbC/GlZ@fg3va4/jgYWis4ko1jxU294WG9CthqPhZ7c37wzGOraBIMWypEZLehHnnTsMd2448u6lqANf4ZduuIzhyTKjZpSsPxSZ538umtultScxmEvcX88@DOJKgsXQm2/myt1ZX7BqWSaMU9xfVqTjkSBQMT5I3vPPqbEEOerjCoSJqDgOrweD3kqXRL4nkI2822JoIwjGBHSZ9cdyWih@FjYYcP7rBxE33u8g@rgygkUr4ZGXqs4EKC@BesPIowh@7F3HfD9I25qOt41yci2xhfVFXboOtbYzviZ8IUaW5S9RQWJ1rRDaBITeDuCA05jcq11@tDRK3wlTvKXSvr5/3irNAvpj3jYt94r3dcIXutf/xKD7nYR6gh0DSAMrW2ETHuHmMObctokZfvICt9GpDv3qXsIN@/jXwlhy51v19LognRAnHZJhDNGBgw@zm0a1vjNGpRLCoWEApBq01TvuyF67ICDVG6kjw8hNeKlANwBqIpqb7E/5tryD0sNiFullIYTvdO33m4owerAXe1gQkhTzDR8By23LwpyMq9jg2XvNaszRjSlByKE7s@nQ84ynQUkZ1ttgNCqjU3DrWnXpWaEKu6lBx/7bWUjzx2y5qbOA219pY@vZuc3G2aKgtFwxHW51JRyWgqidzuah1zNRq0NXJUpJCdDBaQjOM@c019Cj5IwZXxnUJKd@rdLJwFDGUAKDOsdmldHboC6Q4lsA6incyzmjinNZPKqkP@2kU3aMuyyFNbEom2lgIxYcBCVIWMyfozUZt85kyqKDxT4mElzba57TS9y5vsQS0JPfhlxc9vFGuVbc7tTja3N5fzeh5@hR/@6p4oDIKRi2CzUmQ2F8u8Rj0d3tzc2FcBrTGQsc3Lm6h7RdBzb1wxw0FqX@F7HvlA7ENiw2fNO54wK@5n3fsh/DpBBlIUfrDh3s7xs/lLnCcyBvoMeh6Xj/ezNt/Oye7V7irZ11JBKxLSOgZfFX@f@ROFZPLbO9o0B8DMhs@bLziGDn29lU87n/O@JgoXvvfz5/8):

[image: img]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I saw that you calculated the whole dataset together, that's a brilliant idea.
But the fact is that I need to create the image every timesteps, I want to simulate real live data stream. 
This is why I would like to optimise only this part of the code :
    for xxx in range(image_width):
        final_image[:int(vol_norm[xxx]), xxx, :] = 1

Comment: @user3639702 Just updated my answer with animation image, this is an alternative to using CV2 way of visualizing your data. Code for creating such animation image is attached at the end of answer.

Comment: @user3639702 You can use same optimization technique like I did (computing whole image) but for your live stream. You just do next thing - you fetch as many columns as possible of live stream. Render image of this many columns. In another thread show live animation. Then this rendering took some time, maybe 20 new columns arrived, so you compute again image of 20 pixel width and animate it, etc. I mean that you need to compute in batches, by several columns at a time. Then you'll be fast enough to render real-time data.

Comment: @user3639702 I can implement this simulation process of real-time fetching in my code if needed. I'm sure your code is fast enough for computing many thousands of columns in a fraction of seconds. The only thing is that you don't need to recompute whole image again and again, this is the only slow operation. You need to recompute only new columns that just arrived in live stream.

Comment: The main idea why I remake the whole image every timesteps is because I want to make sure that all the data are normalized together.
For exemple, if the new collumn has a maximum value that is bigger than the value that I already calculated in the image, then I need to recalculate the whole image based on that new maximum value to have a normalized image.

Comment: In the real live data stream that I have, I got very different minimal and maximal value throw-out the day.
For exemple in the morning the min could be 3 and the max 20 but in the next hour I could have a pick with a min at 400 and a max at 5000.
This is why I would like to normalise the image every timesteps.

Comment: @user3639702 I just made **Update** to my answer. I've created code that simulates live stream of random data, generation, collecting, rendering and visualizing, all in separate threads. I've also added details to my answer about how everything is organized. I didn't notice your comment regarding normalizing together with previous data, I think about your comment now, to figure out what can be done.

Comment: @user3639702 Just added optimization that you really requested in your question, I've optimized your inner loop through comparing to `np.arange()` instead of pure-Python for loops. Read about this optimization and corrected code in the beginning of my answer.

Comment: @user3639702 Just updated my answer, the very last code snippet, first I simulated process of real-life-like changing value, similar to Forex prices, second I'v implemented mentioned before optimization which is not recomputing whole image if min/max didn't change, also did all other optimizations (like using `np.arange` instead of inner loop), third I implemented rendering of `PNG` of 1000 first frames, if PIL library is installed (`python -m pip install pillow`) and showed this image at the very end of my answer.

Comment: You are a genius ! Every things you said is right, you exaclty understand what kind of data I am working with.

Comment: I use live streaming of futures contract which are working as the same way as forex or bitcoin as you mentioned.
I need to work on 3d images cause my idea is to stack 3 2d image together, every channel will represent a different image. And then I will need to pass them to a convolutive NN. 
I dont know if the neural net could interpret np.uint8 cause most paper I saw used np.float32
I have to take some time to understand every piece of code you putted their. Thank you so much for ur help

Comment: My first goal is to make this image creation faster, the use of cv2 was here to make sure the data created were exactly as intended, but thanks for the work you did on that to I will take the time to understand how you made this even faster with matplotlib. This is a great amount of help you did their, thank bro !

Comment: Actualy I will feed the image directly into the neural net, this is why I used only 1 instead of 255. Because conv neural nets only work well on normalised data.

Comment: I am really impressed how you created a data stream that look like a real forex price change, this is incredible ...

Comment: The use of threading is very cleaver to, so it means that the image creation and the plot creation are using a different thread so they don't 'wait' for each other to run right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222952/discussion-between-arty-and-user3639702).